# writing to CSV works on localhost. Does not work on Website

Tags: python, flask

I have created a basic web app that takes input and does math then returns output. I added a function to take the inputs and write them to a .csv file.

After tinkering with it I got it to work exactly as I wanted running it as localhost. I uploaded the new app and the blank .csv file but whenever I go to run the app now it does not load the results page and nothing is written to the .csv I have even put identical .csv files in multiple locations (in the static, templates and root folder) in case it wasn't looking where I expected

I am still learning python and flask and dealing with hosting and because I am not getting an error output just a non-loading web page I don't know where to start. Ideas?

Here is my code: but as I said it works on local host. And the site worked fine before I added in the section to write to a .csv
(note the indents are off because of pasting it in here. they are correct in practice)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def step_bet():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        people_start = request.form['people_start']
        bet_amount = request.form['bet_amount']
        people_remain = request.form['people_remain']
        beta = request.form['beta']
        #form = web.input(name="nobody", people_start="null", bet="null", people_remain="null", beta="0")
        if people_start == None or bet_amount == None or people_remain == None:
            return render_template('error_form.html')
        else:
            people_startf = float(people_start)
            betf= float(bet_amount)
            people_remainf = float(people_remain)
            if beta == "Yes":
                cut = .125
            elif beta == "Members":
                cut = 0
            else:
                cut = .25       
            revenue = round((((people_startf * betf) * (1 - cut)) / people_remainf),2)
            if revenue < betf:
                revenue = betf
            profit = round((revenue - betf),2)
            people_remain_needed = int(((people_startf * betf) * (1 - cut))/betf)
            people_needed = int(people_remainf - people_remain_needed)
            if people_needed < 0:
                people_needed = 0
            else:
                pass
            # This array is the fields your csv file has and in the following code
            # you'll see how it will be used. Change it to your actual csv's fields.
            fieldnames = ['name', 'people_start', 'bet_amount', 'people_remain', 'beta', 'revenue', 'profit', 'people_needed']
            # We repeat the same step as the reading, but with "w" to indicate
            # the file is going to be written.
            # The second parameter with open is the mode, w is write, a is append. With append it automatically seeks to the end of the file.
            with open('step_bet_save.csv','a') as inFile:
                # DictWriter will help you write the file easily by treating the
                # csv as a python's class and will allow you to work with
                # dictionaries instead of having to add the csv manually.
                writer = csv.DictWriter(inFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

                # writerow() will write a row in your csv file
                writer.writerow({'name': name, 'people_start': people_start, 'bet_amount': bet_amount, 'people_remain': people_remain, 'beta': beta, 'revenue': revenue, 'profit': profit, 'people_needed': people_needed})
            return render_template('results.html', revenue=revenue, profit=profit, name=name, people_needed=people_needed)
    else:
        return render_template('stepbet_form.html')
```

Comment: have you checked the csv file permissions on the server?

Comment: I set permissions on both tie file and folder to 777

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on the file/folder and ensure there is write access to the folder.

Refer to CHMOD if you're not 100% sure how to do this on a *nix based web server.

Comment: I set the permissions on both the file and folder it is in to 777 no change unfortunately. The results page still does not work and the csv still does not get written to.

Comment: What if you use an explicit file path?